# If #REF! then hide certain rows

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have created 2 sheets, Sheet no. 1 shows the data nicely and the other imports the data. Therefore sheet no. 1 gets data from sheet no. 2. However sometimes there are no data in sheet no 2. This gives the cells in sheet 1 "#REF!". When this happens i need to hide certain rows in sheet 1.

So i imagine something like this

```
Sub HideCharts()

BeginRow = 132
EndRow = 138
ChkCol = 8

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next RowCnt

        For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
            If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value <> 0 Then
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

However this only works if the data is 0 and i got no clue on how to catch the #REF! also this only hides the rows that contains the 0 value, but i need to catch certain rows like 130 to 140

So i thought, who else to turn to than Stack Overflow?

Comment: use `ISERROR` function to check for any kind of error in a cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

Change `If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then` to `If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 or iserror(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value)`

```
Sub HideCharts()

BeginRow = 132
EndRow = 138
ChkCol = 8

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 or iserror(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) Then
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else  
        'You don't need this if all the rows are visible at start  
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!

I created the else statement to show the row again, if data there will be data again, and then i created a macro to check.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
Call Sheet1.HideCharts
    End If

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "IsError" in your if statement it should work.

```
For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If IsError(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)) Then
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next RowCnt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch cell value errors using the `IsError` function.

If you only want specific cell value errors (for example because you don't want to hide errors that are not caused by missing data but by corrupt data), use the `CVErr` function. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/ff839168.aspx) for a list of possible error values. In your case it would be

```
If CVErr(Cells(...)) = xlErrRef Then
```